# KStream to KTable

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
@StreamListener("input")
@SendTo("output")
public KStream<?, MyObject> process(KStream<Object, IncomingObject> input) {
KTable table = input.flatMapValues(value -> this.getMylogic(value));            
return table.toStream();
}
```

I am trying to convert KStream to KTable and then to KStream but I am getting **cannot convert from KStream to KTable**

value is json. Kindly help and how can i use aggregation also?

```
{
"name":"test",
address{
"localAddress":"myaddress",
"businessAddress":"testAddress"
}
}
```

in mylogic method I am taking only address to send to another topic.
Kindly help

Comment: method `flatMapValues` returns `KStream` and not `KTable `

Comment: yes, So  how to convert from  kstream to ktable?

Comment: you haven't write the purpose why do you need `KTable`. to get KTable you could use the following: `kStream.groupByKey().aggregate(..)`

Comment: what is the purpose to create Ktable ? Can you provide expected output details in the ktable?

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#how-can-i-convert-a-kstream-to-a-ktable-without-an-aggregation-step

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply aggregate function, such as *count* to get KTable as result. Otherwise there's no way to do KStream -> KTable -> KStream.

What you need, and can do, is KStream.count() (for example) -> KTable -> KStream. So basically results of aggreagtion will be published to KStream, which might be also published into the Kafka topic.